# How do we find this function cardinalities?

Tags: contest-math

Let $x$ and $y$ be sets and $|x|$ and $|y|$ are their respective cardinalities. It is given that there are exactly $97$ functions from $x$ to $y$.From this we can conclude that:

a) $|x|=1 ,|y|= 97$

b) $|x|= 97,|y|=1$

c) $|x|=97, |y|= 97$

d) None

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Also, read: [https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference](MathJax) on how to format your question.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What is you definition of a "function" $f:X \to Y$ ? Does every $x \in X$ has an image $f(x)$ in $Y$ ?

Comment: No answer to my simple question ?